# The updated state in one function is not in sync inside the other one, which sends it to the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When I click on this button:

```js
<Button
  onClick={(e) => {
    addToCard(item);
    handleprisma();
  }}
>
  add to cart
</Button>
```

This function wants to add the item to my card:

```
  const addToCard = (item) => {
    const newCard = {
      fff: "1",
      ddd:  "2",
      aa: "3",
      dfdfdf:  "4",
      asdf:  "5",
      teest:  "6",
    
    };
    context.setcount(context.count + 1);
    context.setcard((prev) => [...prev, newCard]);
  };
```

And this one wants to send it to my database:

```
  const testtt= context.card;
  async function handleprisma() {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/Me', {
      testtt,
    });
    console.log(res.data);
  }
```

And by default, the value of the card is `[]` so I think when I click on the button it does not run the `addToCard`!
But on the second click in the database, I see that the array that should have been created on the first click is there, and when I click again, I see that the array that should have been created on the second click is there.

I solved this problem with this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (context.card.length !== 0) {
      handleprisma();
    }
   
  }, [addToCard]);
```

So when I have 1 item in my card and if I refresh the page, 3 or 4 new copies of the same thing will be created in the database, so how can I just stop getting those copies?

I wanted to use `useCallback` to solve this problem so I converted that `useEffect` to:

```
  useCallback(() => {
    if (context.card.length !== 0) {
      handleprisma();
    }
    console.log('sfd');
  }, [addToCard]);
```

and to:

```
  useCallback(() => {
    if (context.card.length !== 0) {
      handleprisma();
    }
    console.log('sfd');
  }, [context.card]);
```

But why is nothing happening when I click on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Your original attempt is the way to go. No need to use `useEffect` or `useCallback` here. The only thing you are missing is that when you call a `setState`, a re-render is needed before getting the updated value, as the [doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-caveats) says:

> The set function only updates the state variable for the next render. If you read the state variable after calling the set function, you will still get the old value that was on the screen before your call.

## Solution

What you can do, is to ti call `handleprisma` inside `addToCard`, like so:

```
const addToCard = (item) => {
  const newCard = {
    //...
  };
  context.setcount(context.count + 1);
  context.setcard((prev) => [...prev, newCard]);
  //  pass the data as parameter
  handleprisma([...context.card, newCard]);
};
```

And change `handleprisma` so it uses the given `card` to it as a parameter:

```
async function handleprisma(card) {
  const res = await axios.post("/api/Me", {
    card,
  });
  console.log(res.data);
}
```

```
<Button
  onClick={(e) => {
    //  Only addToCard is called here
    addToCard(item);
  }}
>
  add to cart
</Button>
```